# Rendering 3D text in JavaFX 8

Tags: 3d, javafx

Is it possible to render text in 3D view in JavaFX 8?
I have not seen any text rendering in any of the 3D examples I found so far.

Comment: You can just add a Text node to the 3D scene.  It has a Z dimension of 0 so it's pretty thin.  It looks fine from head on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render 3D text in JavaFX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32257311/how-to-render-3d-text-in-javafx)