# How to render 3D text in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-3d

I'm making my first JavaFX project and I need to render some 3D text. I already put a PerspectiveCamera and I display a text node but it has a Z-dimension of 0 and I don't know how to change this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the [FXyz](https://github.com/Birdasaur/FXyz) project. It already contains a [Text3DMesh](https://github.com/Birdasaur/FXyz/blob/master/src/org/fxyz/shapes/primitives/Text3DMesh.java) class that will allow you generating a 3D mesh for any string and font you need.

[image: Text3D]

Under the hood there is a complex process of converting (2D) Text to Path, Delaunay triangulation and mesh extrusion.

[image: Text3D]

As a result, you have a 3D mesh that can be easily rendered and textured (solid color, density map, images).

Have a look at the [sample](https://github.com/Birdasaur/FXyz/blob/master/src/org/fxyz/tests/Text3DTest.java) to get you started.

Comment: Thanks José! I will look at it

Comment: Do you know if it will run in a Raspberry Pi 2?

Comment: It should work, you just need to enable 3D flag, since it's an experimental feature.

Comment: Hi @José, I mangaed to compile the project and to render some 3d text but ANT couln't generate the Javadoc and I'm a little confused on how to use FXyz, is there a Javadoc online?

Comment: No, there isn't. We have quite a bunch of tests to try all the shapes and the different options. Also you can have a look at the [Sampler](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz). Also check this [post](http://jperedadnr.blogspot.com/2015/01/creating-and-texturing-javafx-3d-shapes.html).

Comment: @codenoob
If you still have specific questions on the FXyz test examples, by all means ask them via the GitHub site and we will answer there.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, but isn't there a way to give some kind of 3D perspective to text using what JavaFX already has?

Comment: You can apply 3D rotations, like in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28762212/3956070)... but still it will be 2D.